# When I redo using this undo/redo code, the first thing undone cannot be redone

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-4.0, richtextbox, undo-redo

I am using the following code in order to implement undo/redo into my application:

```
    public struct UndoSection
    {
        public string Undo;
        public int Index;   
}
```

--

```
 public UndoSection(int index, string undo)
    {
        Index = index;
        Undo = undo;
    }
```

--

```
            Stack<UndoSection> UndoStack = new Stack<UndoSection>();
 private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Modifiers == Keys.None && e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
                UndoStack.Push(new UndoSection(richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectionStart, richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectedText));
            else if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.Z)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                undo_Click(richTextBoxPrintCtrl1, new EventArgs());
            }
        }

     public string[] RTBRedoUndo;
        public int StackCount = 0;
        public int OldLength = 0;
        public int ChangeToSave = 5;
        public bool IsRedoUndo = false;
```

--

```
    public void RTBTextChanged()
    {
        if (richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.TextLength - OldLength >= ChangeToSave | richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.TextLength - OldLength <= ChangeToSave)
        {
            StackCount += 1;
            RTBRedoUndo[StackCount] = richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text;
        }
    }

    public void UndoCode()
    {
        IsRedoUndo = true;
        if (StackCount > 0 && RTBRedoUndo[StackCount - 1] != null)
        {
            StackCount = StackCount - 1;
            richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text = RTBRedoUndo[StackCount];
        }
    }

    public void RedoCode()
    {
        if (IsRedoUndo == false && richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text.Substring(richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text.Length - 1, 1) == " ")

            IsRedoUndo = true;
        if (StackCount > 0 && RTBRedoUndo[StackCount + 1] != null)
        {
            StackCount = StackCount + 1;
            richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text = RTBRedoUndo[StackCount];
        }
```

However, if I type some text in my rich text box such as: "Hello. This is my application.", It will only let me redo up to "my". It won't let me redo "application.". And if I undo all text, I then cannot redo and restore the text.

What is causing this to behave in this manner? I really need to get this undo/redo code working correct. Could somebody help point me in the right direction, please?

--EDIT--

Redo code:

```
public void RedoCode()
    {
        if (IsRedoUndo == false && richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text.Substring(richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text.Length - 1, 1) == " ")

            IsRedoUndo = true;
        if (StackCount > 0 && RTBRedoUndo[StackCount + 1] != null)
        {
            StackCount = StackCount + 1;
            richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text = RTBRedoUndo[StackCount];
        }

    }
```

It is called by a button click, using RedoCode();

Answer (score 0):

Can you show how to call the Redo function?

as from what I can see you've missed out the below code

```
 private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Modifiers == Keys.None && e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
                UndoStack.Push(new UndoSection(richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectionStart, richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectedText));
            else if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.Z)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                undo_Click(richTextBoxPrintCtrl1, new EventArgs());
            }
            else if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.Y)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                redo_Click(richTextBoxPrintCtrl1, new EventArgs());
            }
```

Comment: Please see edit. I have added your KeyDown code but nothing seems to have changed.